# Inflate a cosine wave

Tags: trigonometry

I have a simple cosine wave: $y=\cos(\pi x/2)$. This equation passes through the points $(0,1), (1,0), (3,0)$ and so on (the black line in the picture). I want to keep these points, but "inflate" the graph more to look like the green graph in the illustration.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlLed.jpg)

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I have tried using roots of 2 through 3 (including square roots, cube roots, and even the  2.3rd root). However, it appears that none of them seem to line up with the green equation (made up of portions of circles. Is there any way to have a "perfectly circular" cosine equation (in terms of radius of the circle for general use) like the green graph? If so, what method or root should I use to achieve this?

To clarify: I am looking for the equation of an "inflated" graph, *and* the equation of a graph that has been "inflated" to its fullest while still being a function (a "perfectly round" cosine equation).

Comment: That question asks for only the "perfectly round" cosine equation, not how to "inflate" it, and the answer is in a signum function, whereas this answer is in (regular?) function form @AndrewD.Hwang .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be overly complicated, but try $$y = \dfrac{\sin^{-1}(\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}x))}{|\sin^{-1}(\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}x))|}\sqrt{1-\dfrac{4}{\pi^2}\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)\right)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you! The equation fits perfectly. Is there a more general form (i.e. for circle with a radius of 3 instead of 1?

Comment: Try changing every $\pi/2$'s to $\pi/6$, and then multiply the whole expression by $3$.

Comment: Oh... You smart-a...

Answer (score 1):

Try

$$y=\sqrt[3]{\cos(\pi/2(x))}$$

That is, take the cube root.  This tends to work well in general.

Comment: Thank you! However, I was wondering if it would be possible to make a "perfectly circular" cosine equation (like the green one) and for general uses, in terms of the radius of the circle. The equation you suggested [comes close](http://i.imgur.com/21g4SnI.jpg), and explains how to inflate the equation, but does not show how to achieve a perfectly round cosine equation.

Comment: @SuperMaku Oh man!  So close!  No, I don't know how to make it a perfect circle other than to literally take some circle graphs and put them together.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y =\cos(\pi x/2 ) ^{1/n}$$

for large positive integers $n=10,11,12..$ inflates the curve as you wish but for positive part $y>0$ only. To get the negative part as well, reflect the curve about x-axis and translate the  entire curve along x-axis through 2 units.

Otherwise  $y= (-1)^k \sqrt{1-(x - 4 k)^2}, ( k=1,2,3...)  $ .Variable $x$ is continuous, $k$ is discrete with unity increments,  has an effect of removing semicircles alternately.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in one equation without drawing the circles individually?

Comment: It is not impossible. But basically it has infinite slope at x-axis crossings. We can take absolute value and  multiply by $ (-1)^ k $